# Asking about weight

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality

The Hubble Telescope weighs more than 11 tons
How do we ask about its weight?

> A. What is the weight of the Hubble Telescope?
>
> B.How much does the Hubble Telescope weigh?
>
> C. How weigh is the Hubble Telescope? Or
>
> D. How heavy is the Hubble Telescope?

Comment: You might also consider options using "mass" instead of "weight", especially in a scientific context.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few ways we can ask this question while being grammatically correct.

> How much does the Hubble Telescope weigh?
>
> What is the weight of the Hubble Telescope
>
> What is the *mass* of the Hubble Telescope? **Mass may be a more accurate metric to be questioning in this example.**
>
> How heavy is the Hubble Telescope? **This may be considered an inappropriate way to ask this question in a field of science.**

Each of these questions essentially means the same thing in a conversation.

Comment: "How heavy" sounds a little bit strange for something like the Hubble Telescope or the Great Wall of China, though. But it's grammatical.

Comment: True. This question probably has more application in a field of science. I edited my answer to reflect that. Let me know if you have any other ideas.

Comment: Actually, what I was trying to point out is not about a scientific context, but rather that "how heavy" sounds a bit strange for something *too large to weigh*.

Answer (score 2):

The options A, B and D are grammatical, but

> C. How weigh is the Hubble Telescope?

is not.